# How to change color on my main navbar, I can't acces it throught CSS neither PHP

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am creating site with King Size theme in Wordpress it is older version of theme 1.4. So here is the CSS of that part of theme but I cant do anything to change it. Now here is the code of inspect element of my main page with that nawbar inside so please if someone can help me.

```css
iv#navContainer {
  top: 0;
  max-width: 240px;
  width: 25%;
  z-index: 3;
}
div#navContainer {
  position: fixed;
}
.front {
  z-index: 2;
}
.hide-for-xlarge, .show-for-large, .show-for-large-up, .hide-for-small, .hide-for-medium, .hide-for-medium-down {
  display: block !important;
}
body, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, form, p, blockquote, th, td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  direction: ltr;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheetdiv {
  display: block;
}
Inherited from 
body, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, form, p, blockquote, th, td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  direction: ltr;
}
Inherited from 
body, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, form, p, blockquote, th, td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  direction: ltr;
}
body {
  background: url(../images/grid.png);
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
p, body {
  color: #CCCCCC;
}
Inherited from 
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Please post the html code too.

Answer (score 0):

Just before uploading the theme, go to "kingsize/images/opacity/90/" and change "menu_back.png".

But keep in mind that the new image should have the same name and format.(menu_back.png)

Answer (score -1):

I find your code difficult to understand given the way you have posted it. Nevertheless, this should solve your problem:

Javascript:

```
window.onload = function(){
window.setInterval(function(){
document.getElementById('navContainer').style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
},50);
};
```

Please tell me what happens. I am happy to follow up if this code doesn't help.